# Уменьшить толщину у ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-animation

Стандартное поведение `ProgressBar` вполне устраивает, но нужно поменять толщину стандартного `ProgressDrawable`.
Но из коробки нет возможности это сделать (ну или я не нашел коробочного решения).

Получится должно следующее: анимация вот как здесь ([пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7k3V.gif)), но толщина линии 2 раза тоньше..

Решил поменять progressDrawable

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_image"/>
```

**loading_image:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <vector
        android:width="113dp"
        android:height="113dp"
        android:viewportWidth="113"
        android:viewportHeight="113">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#000"
            android:pathData="M109.78 68c0.8-3.7 1.22-7.55 1.22-11.5C111 26.4 86.6 2 56.5 2S2 26.4 2 56.5c0 27.56 20.45 50.33 47 53.99v2.02C21.34 108.84 0 85.16 0 56.5C0 25.3 25.3 0 56.5 0S113 25.3 113 56.5c0 3.94-0.4 7.79-1.17 11.5h-2.05z" />
    </vector>
</rotate>
```

Но как следовало ожидать, анимация "деревянная", просто крутится картинка.
Собственно вопрос:

1. Можно ли просто уменьшить толщину стандартного `ProgressDrawable`?
2. Если ответ на первый вопрос нет, то как мне анимировать мою векторную картинку таким образом, чтобы был эффект "растягивания" линии? как в стандартной анимации([пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7k3V.gif)).

**UP1.** Воспользовавшись ответом от Sergei Buvaka получил вот такой результат

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

[Результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzMlj.gif) (почти похоже на то, что нужно)

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример стандартной кастомной крутилки:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360">

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="12dp" // это и есть ваша ширина
    android:thicknessRatio="50"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <size
        android:width="76dip"
        android:height="76dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FDFDFD"
        android:startColor="#012C42"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Это наверное в старых андроидах такой стандартный прогресс, поменял в вопросе "Пример", там нет градиента. Там чуть другой эффект (эффект змейки что ли, не знаю как это назвать)

Comment: Ну так чтоб вам мешает добавить <shape и в нем задать параметр thickness? Ну или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: shape то я добавлю, и  thickness укажу. Но как добиться такой анимации как в примере?) Тут наверное нужно какой то animation-drawable использовать(ну или я не догоняю чего то) , пошел гуглить

Comment: В общем, спасибо :)  добавил, что получилось. Получилось не совсем прям как надо, но дальше думаю разберусь)